# Wordpress 5.4 - How to prevent to enter only certain values in custom field

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

WordPress version - 5.4.2

I am creating one WordPress plugin and in this plugin, I need one metadata for the post. I added meta box `accesstype visibility` successfully. It is a select box and it has only fixed 3 values. it is working fine in block editor as shown below.

[image]

However, when I enable custom fields by going in options. it is allowing me to add any value in the text box and it will save it as shown below.

[image]

How can I hide `accesstype visibility` from it or add a select box instead of a text box?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the meta data private, and not visible on the Custom Fields list, by appending underscore to the meta key. I.e. `_accesstype_visibility`

You can find more details in the WP Developer docs, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/#hidden-custom-fields

---

**EDIT 24.7.2020**

Here's an example how to use [`is_protected_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_protected_meta/) filter to make meta key public or private. You can read more about filters here, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/

```
// first hook we're filtering, second our callback, third priority, fourth # of parameters
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'my_prefix_is_protected_meta', 10, 3 );
// available parameters can be found on the filter documentation
function my_prefix_is_protected_meta( $protected, $meta_key, $meta_type ) {
    // Force custom meta key to be protected
    if ( 'my_meta_key' === $meta_key ) {
        $protected = true;
    }
    // Return filtered value so WP can continue whatever it was doing with the value
    return $protected;
}
```

You can use this in your theme's `functions.php` file or in a [custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/).

Comment: I tried your solution, it is not visible in custom fields any more though it is still visible in the dropdown of add new custom fields. It's not a complete solution. anyways, i tried to hide it by JS and its working fine for now. don't know whether its best solution or not but it worked for me

Comment: @Vishal is it the `accesstype_visibility` or `_accesstype_visibility` that is visible in the custom fields meta select? You should be able to brute force the key out of the list with `is_protected_meta` filter, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_protected_meta/

Comment: It is visible in both cases. I am very new to WordPress not sure how and where to use this is_protected_meta filter, and what exactly it will do.

Comment: @Vishal What happens, if you remove the meta data which has the public key? I.e. execute `delete_post_meta($post_id, 'accesstype_visibility');` once before saving meta data with the private key?

Comment: I added a example on how to use the filter to my answer, if you're interested.